# Report from Business Objects disappeared/being deleted while I was deleting Running instance

Tags: crystal-reports, scheduling, business-objects

A very strange thing happened and I wonder if anyone has experienced this or knows why. I was rescheduling an existing scheduled report in Business Object, after rescheduling, it was trying to run the instance, while the status of the instance has been 'Running' for a while, I thought there is something wrong with the rescheduling instance, so I deleted the instance with the "Running" status, after it is done, the report has disappeared. I have never clicked anything to delete the report, it is very strange. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Where are you performing this operation? in CMC or Infoview?

Comment: In CMC, I right clicked on the report and selected History, performed over there.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Just when you're rescheduling a report the instance's state is "Running", but it's a fake state: the instance isn't doing any refresh but the report is changing the schedule.

I did the same: delete the running instance and I deleted the report (I looking for the file, at the filesystem, and the report was dissapear).

So sorry.

Comment: Thanks @P. Barbadew for letting me know this, I will not touch the 'Running' instance again! Do you know if the reports are backed up automatically in Business Objects?

Comment: Up to BI 4.X no bakcup mechanism exist. I know BI 4.2 SP2 has a recycle bin. Previous versions need to backup fisically the fsrinput/fsroutput folders.